# how to filter the foreignkey field in django

Tags: django, view

i have to make a queryset for only returns that object which is in the M2M field

```
class Item(models.Model):
    items = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Main(models.Model):
    admin = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #others

class TestModel(models.Model):
    admin = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    items = models.ForeignKey(Item,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

i have to make query to filter in `TestModel` to only the items which is in the `Main` model!

i tried this in my views.py

```
  get_id_from_user = request.GET.get('user_input')
  main_obj = Main.objects.get(id=get_id_from_user)
  test_objects = TestModel.objects.filter(items__in=main_obj.items.all()
```

but test_objects still returns all the Item object!
is it possible please
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `get_id_from_user` variable is integer type.

If it doesn't, try do it yourself: `main_obj = Main.objects.get(id=int(get_id_from_user))`

Comment: it is int type , i test it it works fine , still returns all the objects

Answer (score 0):

in main_obj query you use "get" that give only one result, change with

```
test_objects = TestModel.objects.filter(items= main_obj)
```

Comment: its wrong i work only on one Main object , i should use get()